# What is the website for `say` program?

Tags: source

Embarrassing, but after system upgrade `say` vanished from it -- either it is no longer provided by the distro, or I installed it independently before (but I don't remember how and where from).

The problem is `say` word is so ubiquitous word, that google search is useless when looking for it.

*For the record `say` is quite old now program, that can either pronounce the given text or convert it to SAMPA representation. There are probably alternatives (like espeak) but I **have to** get `say`.*

So... anyone remembers/knows what is the website of `say`?

**Update**: finally I found it. It is from [rsynth](http://sourceforge.net/projects/rsynth/) package written by Nick Ing-Simmons.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install gnustep-gui-runtime` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the command to install `say` on ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install gnustep-gui-runtime
```

On other distros, you have to replace `apt-get` with `yum` or whichever package manager you have.

*How I found it:* If you run any command that is not installed in ubuntu (`bash`), then it will automatically tell you how to install it. I also searched google first, but I didn't get it.

This functionality is provided by installing the Debian/Ubuntu package `command-not-found`. (Which is installed by default)

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Now it seems there are too many `says`, I found another one in mbrola package. I wonder if I find the "original" (the one I used before) program -- one piece I remember also, the author died several years ago, that is why it is hard to find.

Answer (score 8):

`apt-file` can be used for queries like this. If you know that `say` is an executable, you can search for `/usr/bin/say`. You could also try `/bin/say`.

```
faheem@orwell:~$ apt-file search /usr/bin/say

gnustep-gui-runtime: /usr/bin/say
libgnustep-gui0.20-dbg: /usr/lib/debug/usr/bin/say
libgnustep-gui0.22-dbg: /usr/lib/debug/usr/bin/say
saytime: /usr/bin/saytime
```

You can also search the contents of packages on [packages.debian.org](http://www.debian.org/distrib/packages#search_contents).